# What is the difference between ADD rA, rB, r0 and ADDI rA, rB, 0?

Tags: assembly, mips

I heard these are very different but why are the results different?

`ADD rA, rB, r0`

is instruction typ R with `r0` that contains 0 so 0 is added to rB and placed in rA that will contain rB+0, right?

`ADDI rA, rB, 0`

this is an instruction typ I but it does the same the first one or won't it?

Comment: "*why are the results different?*" - Why do you believe this is so? The results are the same, the way to achieve them is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to look at the implementation of the specific processor.  If the processor knows on a read of r0 that it can shortcut and make it a zero, then it can be faster than going to the register file to fetch the value for r0.  And that would come into play if there were a lot of register file activity forcing a stall, only adding clocks if there were register file interference over multiple instructions.  Basically, I doubt there is a difference from that perspective.

As far as functionality the two instructions are equivalent as r0 always reads as zero so the result of both operations is.

```
ra = rb + 0.
```

both ADD and ADDI signal overflow, but adding zero to rb you cant get an overflow so it doesnt matter if you use ADD/ADDU or ADDI/ADDIU

Comment: MIPS is a RISC architecture, so `ADD rx,ry,r0` and `ADDI rx,ry,0` both produce a result in one clock cycle. In other words the result is available in `rx` for the succeeding instruction after the add without any pipeline stalls for both versions of this `ADD` instruction. The two instructions have the same functionality and the same performance.

Comment: right, that is not what I was talking about.  I have been reading one of the H and P books lately.  Since r0 is read only I dont actually see how the situation I was thinking of can happen so it is a non issue.